# Odoo 10 - Add order line via XMLRPC

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-10

I am trying to add an order line to an existing sales order via XMLRPC

I am trying this:

```
r = api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'sale.order', 'write',  [[sc]], { 'order_line': (0, '_', {'product_id': id, 'product_uom_qty': qty}) })
```

Where `id`, `qty` are integer numbers, and `sc` is the integer number with the `ID` of the sale order.

I get this error:

```
Fault: <Fault 1: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 56, in xmlrpc_return\n    result = odoo.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 118, in dispatch_rpc\n    result = dispatch(method, params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 38, in dispatch\n    res = fn(db, uid, *params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 157, in execute_kw\n    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper\n    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 164, in execute\n    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 153, in execute_cr\n    return odoo.api.call_kw(recs, method, args, kw)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw\n    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi\n    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)\nTypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument \'order_line\'\n'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes here. One was already pointed at by Sanaullah Khan: A write on `one2many` or `many2many` fields has to be a list of "triplets".

And your call isn't correct. You're using `args` and `kwargs` on the call. The values parameter of `write()` is not a keyword argument/parameter. So get it into the `args`:

```py
r = api.execute_kw(
    db, uid, pwd, 'sale.order', 'write', 
    [[sc], {'order_line': \  # args
        [(0, '_', {'product_id': id, 'product_uom_qty': qty})]}],
    {})  # kwargs
```

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are passing to the field is not in the correct format. It should be a **list of tuples** not just one tuple.

Try passing the following value to it.

```
{ 'order_line': [(0, '_', {'product_id': id, 'product_uom_qty': qty})]}
```

Hopefully it's going to solve the issue your are facing.